# How do I link my bids to posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble linking my bids to posts. I have created a `post_id` column in my bids table (via adding resources:posts in a migration).

> I want to be able to go to /posts/:id/new_bid to create a new bid for
>   that post. Currently, I can create a new bid by going to
>   /posts/2/new_bid (for example), but it still says 'post_id: nil' in
>   the database.

**Routes**

```
root 'static_pages#home'
get 'add' => 'posts#new'
get 'posts' => 'posts#index'
get '/posts/:id/new_bid' => 'bids#new'

resources :posts
resources :bids
```

**Bid Controller**

```
class BidsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @bid = Bid.new
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def show
    @bid = bids.find(params[:id])
end

def index
    @bid = bids.all
end

def create 
    @bid = Bid.new(bid_params)
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    if @bid.save
        redirect_to root_path
        flash[:notice] = 'Bid received!'
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def bid_params
    params.require(:bid).permit(:price, :company_name, :company_street, :company_city,
                                :company_zip, :company_phone, :company_email, :post_id)
end

end
```

**Bid Model**

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
end
```

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bids
end
```

**Schema**

```
 ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150704152313) do

  create_table "bids", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.integer  "post_id"
  end

  add_index "bids", ["post_id"], name: "index_bids_on_post_id"

create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.datetime "created_at", null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
   t.string   "fromstreet"
   t.string   "fromcity"
 end

end
```

Bids form:

```
 <%= form_for(@bid) do |f| %>
   <div style='float: left; width: 50%;'>
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

   <%= f.label "Price" %>
   <%= f.text_field :price, class: "form-control" %>
<br></br>
<%= f.submit "Submit bid", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Can anyone help ?

When I add validation tests to my bids model such as:

```
validates :price, presence: true
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :company_email, presence: true, 
                format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}
```

I get the following error when I enter a bid that violates one of the validation tests:

```
 undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

and the line:

```
  <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id %>
```

is highlighted in red.

Comment: Please update your post with `form` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a `hidden_field` in your form.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id %>
```

Comment: One more thing (see above). Thanks.

Comment: @Ben You should be asking it  as another question :)